# Rails validation required numericality even though presence is not set to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to save a record which doesn't have one field set -- which has a validate numericality in the models. Even though the presence is not required in the validation, it's still throwing an error that the field is not a number.

**Validation:**

```
validates :network_id,    :numericality => true
```

**Code to that is saving model:**

```
networks.each do |network|
  network.url = network.raw_data.link
  network.save!
end
```

**Error:**

```
Validation failed: Network is not a number
```

Answer (score 140, accepted):

```
validates :network_id, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
```

Comment: @Unixmonkey would this be needed for every field in the db that allows null values? or is there a way to let rails handle this automatically (seems kind of a pain the arse to either set presence or allow_nil)

Comment: @Hopstream If you are validating the numericality, then nil is not a numerical value. You have to explicitly allow it. You do not need to do this for all fields.

Comment: Okey but what if i don't want nil values? What if y WANT to save numbers?

Comment: @ExiRe: If you only want numbers, then `validates :network_id, :numericality => true`.  This will raise a validation error if you try to save with a nil value.

Answer (score 43):

```
    validates :network_id, :numericality => {:allow_blank => true}
```

Comment: I think that was the proper way to write it, +1 then

Comment: It is more useful answer

Comment: This is indeed better as it allows empty strings: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank

Comment: With this validation, if you submit a non-numerical value the validation passes but the value is set to blank, which is not what you want

Comment: @ChristerFernstrom I think that your statement here is not correct. At least this is what I have tested here: https://github.com/pmatsinopoulos/test_numericality See the tests on the user model. They are passing green on my end.

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos You're absolutely right! The non-numeric inputs I tested with were caught by the HTML5 number validation of the form field by the browser (Firefox and Safari) which submitted the form with empty values. By setting the form input type to string I could confirm that the rails validation works as it should.

Answer (score 16):

You should use `allow_blank`

```
validates :network_id,    :numericality => true, :allow_blank => true
```

Comment: oh man -- i thought allowing nil was default. Should I be adding that to all fields that are allowed to be nil? kind of seems redundant on rails part.

Comment: @apneadiving I may be wrong ... it should be `    validates :network_id, :numericality => {:allow_blank => true}`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Hopstream: look at my link: The :allow_blank option is similar to the :allow_nil option

Comment: @PanayotisMatsinopoulos: same, look at the link provided but if I recal well that was the case for former versions of Rails

Comment: @apneadiving: but are these needed at all? shouldn't rails handle this since the presence is not set to true?

Comment: @Hopstream: it's needed because of the `numericality` check

Comment: the link you posted for the doc is broken

Answer (score 12):

In Rails 4 (*Ruby 2*), you can write:

```
validates :network_id, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, allow_nil: true }
```

Comment: I dont know why this doesn't work for me. I'm using Rails 4.2. With that validation, I can save with nil value, but it also allow to save string.

Answer (score 2):

You can also write like this...

```
validates_numericality_of :network_id, allow_nil: true
```