# Make db column optional or not required so I can create record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a column on a table that may or may not get populated when a new record is created. Let's call it `free_shipping_amount` and its type `integer`, and it resides in the `shipping_methods` table.

I also have a form that is backed by this `ShippingMethods` model. So I don't want this field to display as `0` because its not zero, its just nothing.

How can I make this column either optional, or not required or something other than zero, or an empty string, because its an integer. Seemingly `nil` and `null` won't work.

I've tried the following migrations, and they all didn't work:

```
change_column :shipping_methods, :free_shipping_amount, :integer, 
default: ""

change_column_null :shipping_methods, :free_shipping_amount, true

change_column :shipping_methods, :free_shipping_amount, :integer,    
:default => nil

change_column_default(:shipping_methods, :free_shipping_amount, nil)

change_column :shipping_methods, :free_shipping_amount, :integer, null: true
```

Then I tried this, but then my model backed form displays the `0` which is not something I want..

```
change_column_default(:shipping_methods, :free_shipping_amount, 0)
```

The field on this table looks like this:

```
t.integer  "free_shipping_amount"
```

The problem is that I can't save a record to this table without passing something to this field.

I use strong parameters that look like this:

```
def shipping_method_params
  params.require(:shipping_method).permit(:free_shipping_amount) 
  #other values removed for brevity
end
```

and when I create like this:

```
@shipping_shop = ShippingMethod.create(shipping_method_params)
```

The record is not created, and the transaction is rolled back.

Oh geez.. I have this in the model.

```
validates :free_shipping_amount, numericality: true
```

So how can I save this model without passing in a value for this field?? Or can I and still validate numericality?

Comment: you don't actually have to do anything. by default the field is going to be optional unless you have a validation for presence.

Comment: Can you look in `db/schema.rb` and post the lines relevant to `free_shipping_amount`?

Comment: What exactly is the issue/error that you're facing? You say that you don't want this field to display as 0. Can you show us the code that is displaying it as 0? An integer column CAN be nil, and it is possible that it IS nil, but is being displayed as 0.

Comment: I updated the question to try and answer everyone's questions. The record won't save.. When I pass in a value to that field it saves fine..

Comment: I updated again.. I have this in the model: validates :free_shipping_amount, numericality: true but I need that to be there.. what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arghhhhhhh.. I just found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981351/rails-validation-required-numericality-even-though-presence-is-not-set-to-true) It was my model that was jacked.. I have to add this to the validation in order to accept a blank value.

```
validates :free_shipping_amount, numericality: {allow_blank: true}
```

Thanks for everyone's time and pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

@ToddT I did this migration

```
class AddFieldToShippingMethods < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :shipping_methods, :free_shippping_amount2, :integer
  end
end
```

and this [demo](https://secret-springs-85211.herokuapp.com/)

It's not mandatory set default values on your migrations

[]'s